# Batch : remove empty lines of all files in a folder and the subfolders

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a batch to remove all empty lines of all files in the current folder and subfolder.

myscript.bat :

```
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /s /b /a-d') do (
    if NOT "%%f"==%0 (
        for /F "delims=" %%l in (%%f) do (
            if NOT "%%l"=="" echo %%l>>logtemp.txt
        )
        del "%%f"
        move "logtemp.txt" "%%f"
    )
)
```

Folder hierarchy:

- myscript.bat
- f1.txt
- My folder

  - f2.txt

f1.txt and f2.txt are simple test files with empty lines.
It works with f1.txt, but f2.txt is simply remove.

Comment: `for /F` ignores empty lines anyway, so the `if not "%%l"==""` query is not necessary. `if not "%%f"==%0"` should read `if not "%%f"=="%~f0"`. Change `del "%%f"` to `del "logtemp.txt"` and move it in front of the `for /F %%l` line. Insert the `/Y` option to the `move` command line.

Comment: A powershell one liner with aliases editing all files `*.txt` recursively from current folder `powershell -NoP -C "gci *.txt -r -file |%{$fn=$_.fullname;(gc $fn)|?{$_ -ne ''}|set-content $fn}"`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the fact that [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) ignores empty lines anyway:

```cmd
rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=%~dp0."
set "_MASK=*.*"
set "_TEMP=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp"
rem // Walk through all matching files recursively:
for /R "%_ROOT%" %%F in ("%_MASK%") do (
    rem // Exclude this script:
    if /I not "%%~fF"=="%~f0" (
        rem // Write content of file to temporary file:
        > "%_TEMP%" (
            rem // Read file line by line, ignoring empty ones:
            for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%%~F") do (
                rem // Just return every non-empty line:
                echo(%%L
            )
        )
        rem // Move temporary file onto original one:
        move /Y "%_TEMP%" "%%~F"
    )
)
```

Comment: Clever! Your addition of slashes to REM statements is interesting, is that a convention somewhere I missed or just something you do for readability?

Comment: The `//` have no special meaning to batch, I use them here for remarks because syntax highlighting of this site recognises them...

Comment: I knew they had no meaning in the file itself. Wow, clever syntax *and* a clever answer. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /r %%A in (*) do (
  findstr /v "^$" "%~fA" > "%~dpnA.new"
  ren "%~dpnA.new" "%%~nxA"
)
```

`for /r` provides all files recursively (including those in sub folders).
`findstr` excludes (`/v`) all lines that are empty (`^` = StartOfLine, `$` = EndOfLine) and writes the rest to a new file. The `ren` command then renames the new file to the original name.

Pro: faster than reading each file line by line; no worries about special chars.

Contra (or maybe even a Pro - depending on your intention): this removes "true empty" lines. Lines that contain just space(s) are not really empty and will not be removed.